# How to plot figure of merit vs blade loading coefficient for helicopter rotor?

Tags: helicopter, blade

I know the formula of figure of merit and blade loading coefficient individually but how the plot can be obtained I am not getting that. What would be the formula for figure of merit in terms of blade loading coefficient. Formulas I know are:
[image: Formula]

Comment: Please edit your question to include which equations you have to start with.  There is nothing we can do to help this question without simply doing your homework for you -- and that is not the purpose of this forum.

Comment: @RobMcDonald when the FOM, coefficient of thrust, solidity of the rotor all are fixed which will be the variable in the plot?

Comment: My definition of blade loading coefficient is ($C_T/\sigma$).  Plotting FOM vs. $C_T/\sigma$ is a common thing to do.  Typically, the $C_T/\sigma$ variation represents a change in collective for a fixed rotor -- which means that $C_T$ is varying.  Again -- please share the formulas you have and we can help show how to use them - or suggest the missing formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the rotor 'polar' equation.  While not exactly the same as an aircraft's drag polar, it plays that role in performance equations.

$C_P=\frac{\kappa {C_T}^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sigma C_{d,0}}{8}$

An ideal rotor has $\kappa$=1 and $C_{d,0}$=0.  Such a rotor has $FM$=1.0.

The $\kappa$ is a non-ideal induced flow factor.  It plays the same role as an Oswald efficiency factor, but is inverted in definition.  A typical value might be $\kappa$=1.15.

The $C_{d,0}$ is the airfoil profile drag coefficient.  It contributes to form the profile drag power.  A typical value is $C_{d,0}$=0.01.

The figure of merit $FM$ is the ratio of the ideal power to actual power.

$FM=\frac{\mathrm{ideal}}{\mathrm{actual}}$

I.e. applying it to our definition above, we get...

$FM=\frac{ \frac{{C_T}^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{\kappa {C_T}^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sigma C_{d,0}}{8} }$

Which you should be able to plot.

Comment: How to get the value of k?

Comment: You perform complex analysis on your rotor design -- including planform, airfoils, twist, etc.  Ideally under loaded conditions as rotors deflect substantially when operating.  Or you measure performance of your rotor and choose k to match the data.  Or you use historical data for similar rotors.  Typical is 1.15 -- 1.0 is ideal, you can't go lower than that.